# what's the difference between python objects and json objects?

Tags: javascript, python, django, json, node.js

On the surface it appears that python uses json natively. The only exception I can think of is the fact that json can store js functions.

Here's my issue:
I need to pass json to a python file through the terminal.
Why should or shouldn't I just use eval()?

Comment: "it appears that python uses json natively"?  Since there's a separate `json` library, I don't get this statement at all.  It seems like a separate library would indicate that JSON is not a first-class part of Python's syntax.

Comment: Really the question should be something like 'What is the difference between python object literal syntax and JSON?'.  Also, don't use eval - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/397719

Comment: I appreciate your answer @SpacedMonkey. I watched a presentation by a guy at twitter (I believe) discuss how JSON.parse() falls back to eval in some situations and how rules of thumb are only rules of thumb. But for someone like me who doesn't want to investigate all the eery details, not using eval is the right way to go.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what "pass json to a python file through the terminal" means in this case, but if you don't control the string you `eval` you might make yourself vulnerable to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JSON does not have objects per se, and cannot store JavaScript functions. Its syntax may appear similar to JavaScript literals, but trying to use it as such all the time will cause nothing but pain.

And there should be no need to use `eval()`; both JavaScript and Python have JSON parsers and serializers readily available.

Comment: well, using `eval()` in python seems to be a lot easier to do than importing extra json libraries to parse serialized data. It seems to work well, but what are the things I should watch out for?

Comment: The big thing you should watch for is that **`eval()` will accept things that are not JSON.**

Comment: well besides that, I just want to know the difference. python data: `{'a':'b'}`, json data: `{'a':'b'}` ... what's the difference?

Comment: The latter is not JSON, since it's not a string.

Comment: oh ok, I think I might be getting what you're saying now. It's pretty subtle, but yeah.

Comment: maybe you could answer me this: if in python I put `a = {'b':'c'}`, then couldn't I just serialize `a` to json by putting `str(a)`? It looks right

Comment: @Stephen: Generally?  No.  In that specific case, it happens to work out.

Comment: @S.Lott why not? what is the difference? could you find me a counter example?

Comment: Ok thank you! That makes perfect sense now, I just had to see it.

Comment: The comments here are so much revealing!

Answer (score 27):

No, Python does not use JSON natively. This stuff you think is JSON is, in fact, a dictionary, *one* of many kinds of objects in Python. The (easy) syntax for building a dictionary in Python is pretty close to JSON but it is incidental. As you can create a dictionary this way:

```
a = {'a' : 2, 'b' : 3}
```

you can create it this way, too:

```
a = dict([('a', 2), ('b', 3)]);
```

So, what are the syntaxes so similar? Well, JSON syntax is *inspired* by JavaScript syntax for arrays. It is likely that the JavaScript syntax *also inspired* the way Python dictionaries are written or vice versa. But never assumes these three syntaxes – JavaScript, JSON and Python dicts - to be the same or interchangeable.

Given that, why should you not use `eval()` for convert JSON in a dictionary? Firstly, because `eval()` can do anything in Python – such as exiting the program, removing a file, changing some internal data etc. etc. Hence, by using `eval()`, you might make yourself vulnerable to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), depending on how you use it. Also, using `eval()` for converting JSON to a dict assumes the syntax of both are identical – which is not necessarily true; even if the syntaxes were identical, they cannot be in the future. Finally, there is a much better and more practical way to parse JSON: the `json` module:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"a":1}')
{'a': 1}
```

Use it to parse your JSON.

Good luck!