# Is JSON syntax a strict subset of Python syntax?

Tags: javascript, python, json, syntax

JSON is very similar to Python syntax. Can all JSON objects directly convert to Python without error?

**Example**

The following is a valid JSON object:

```
// Valid JSON
{"foo":"bar"}
```

This object will directly translate to a Python dictionary with key "foo" and value "bar":

```
# Python
json_dict = eval('{"foo":"bar"}')
```

Comment: Giving your question the benefit of the doubt, could you give me an example of JSON that could be python code?

Comment: @IRegretable: I can copy and paste the examples from http://json.org/example.html directly into the Python interpreter and get back a valid dictionary.

Comment: I don't know python well enough to know for sure, but there may be cases where python's parsing of the json string differ from the json spec

Comment: @James: This question has nothing to do with the *parsing* of JSON, but rather with the *direct consumption* of it.

Comment: Understood, but if python parses differently than the spec, then it affects the answer to the main question "Can all JSON objects directly convert to Python without error". Coercion/mutation is an error in my mind

Comment: I'm concerned about how the answer to this question will be used.  `eval(jsondata)` isn't much faster than `simplejson.loads(jsondata)` and far less secure.  Why do you have this question?

Comment: It's definitely insecure with an untrusted source of JSON data. I copy and paste a lot of JSON between Python scripts for small automation tasks so my code is isolated from external threats. More of a question concerning convenience than speed.

Comment: There's also `ast.literal_eval` which is much safer than `eval`.

Comment: +1 FogleBird, I wonder if you can implement a safe and fast JSON parser using this method combined with defining variables true, false, and null.

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584943/whats-the-difference-between-python-objects-and-json-objects/5585962#5585962).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. In particular, `true`, `false`, and `null` are not Python, although they do have direct equivalents in Python (`True`, `False`, and `None` respectively).

```
// Valid JSON
{"sky_is_blue":true}
```

But when used in Python...

```
# Python
>>> json_dict = eval('{"sky_is_blue":true}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Comment: +1 That's good to know. Is that the full extent of incompatibilities or are there a lot of other Javascript specific stuff that Python doesn't like?

Comment: Strings can get a bit fuzzy depending on which way you interpret the specs (or lack thereof), but these three are the big differences.

Comment: I've seen some JSON with no quotes around the dictionary keys.

Comment: In javascript, you are allowed to have string keys in your dicts without quotes: {a : 1}.  Python requires that you use quotes: {"a" : 1}.

Comment: @FogleBird: No you haven't; that's not JSON.

Comment: As far as I know, these are the only *strict* JSON values which aren't in Python. Values like `NaN` and `Infinity` aren't strictly JSON, but may be found in JSON strings (indeed, Python's json module will use them unless specifically told not to).

Comment: @Ignacio: You're right. I guess people abuse JSON like HTML sometimes.

Comment: Updated question to demonstrate this answer.

Answer (score 6):

This question has been answered (and the answer accepted) already, but I'd like to point out that the problem of `true`, `false` and `null` not being Python can be overcome by using the following code before evaluating JSON:

```
true = True
false = False
null = None
```

Of course, a JSON-parser is still better.

Comment: I wonder if this combined with the `ast.literal_eval` mentioned by FogleBird above could be used to construct a fast pure Python JSON parser.

Comment: Not really, as variables are not literals and thus not allowed... although one could do a `string.replace('true', 'True')` etc. before passing to `ast.literal_eval`. Of course, that does nasty things to `{"Quote": "This sentence is false."}`.

Comment: A regex? Now you have two problems! ;)