# API/JSON Value Error

Tags: json, decode

I've been trying to use an API with the following response when I type in the url:

```
{
    "resource": "playerdashptshotlog",
    "parameters": {
        "LeagueID": "00",
        "Season": "2014-15",
        "SeasonType": "Regular Season",
        "PlayerID": 202066,
        "TeamID": 0,
        "Outcome": null,
        "Location": null,
        "Month": 0,
        "SeasonSegment": null,
        "DateFrom": null,
        "DateTo": null,
        "OpponentTeamID": 0,
        "VsConference": null,
        "VsDivision": null,
        "GameSegment": null,
        "Period": 0,
        "LastNGames": 0
    },
    "resultSets": [
```

My code is as follows:

```
import json, requests
github_url = 'http:dsds
parsed_input = json.loads(github_url)
print (parameters.keys())
print (parameters['LeagueID']['Season'])
```

I get an error when I use Python34 saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\Scripts\NBA
>   API-JSON.py", line 27, in 
>       parsed_input = json.loads(github_url)   File "C:\Python34\lib\json__init__.py", line 318, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
>       raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

When I run it on Python27 I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\NBA
>   API-JSON.py", line 27, in 
>       parsed_input = json.loads(github_url)   File "C:\Python27\lib\json__init__.py", line 338, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
>       raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried using an example answer I found to a question found at:

[Parsing Multidimensional JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344332/parsing-muilti-dimensional-json-array-to-python)

Comment: Did you not copy all of your response, because what you pasted isn't valid JSON, it ends with an open `[`

Comment: It's about 60 pages worth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to fetch the data. Try:

```
github_url = 'http://whatever'
r = requests.get(github_url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    parsed_input = json.loads(r.text)
```

Requests can also parse the JSON for you:

```
parsed_input = r.json()
```

Comment: And how can I just print certain fields, eg: TeamID, PlayerID etc? So that I may manipulate any of these values later on like be in a tabular format.

Comment: @RossJohnson I don't think that's relevant to your question. I believe that this answer answers your question. If you think it does then it would be best to upvote/accept it. I'd suggest creating another question for this with more details.

Comment: json.loads() returns a regular python dict or list, depending what the input JSON is.  In your case do parsed_input['parameters']['TeamID'] and so on.