# python ijson not working on multiple element at once

Tags: python, json, ijson

I have thousands of very large JSON files that I need to process on specific elements. To avoid memory overload I am using a python library called [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) which works fine when I am processing only a single element from the json file but when I try to process multiple-element at once it throughs

> IncompleteJSONError: parse error: premature EOF

**Partial JSON:**

```
{
  "info": {
    "added": 1631536344.112968,
    "started": 1631537322.81162,
    "duration": 14,
    "ended": 1631537337.342377
  },
  "network": {
    "domains": [
      {
        "ip": "231.90.255.25",
        "domain": "dns.msfcsi.com"
      },
      {
        "ip": "12.23.25.44",
        "domain": "teo.microsoft.com"
      },
      {
        "ip": "87.101.90.42",
        "domain": "www.msf.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Working Code:** (Multiple file open)

```
my_file_list = [f for f in glob.glob("data/jsons/*.json")]
final_result = []
for filename in my_file_list:
    row = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        info = ijson.items(f, 'info')
        for o in info:
             row['added']= float(o.get('added'))
             row['started']= float(o.get('started'))
             row['duration']= o.get('duration')
             row['ended']= float(o.get('ended'))
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        domains = ijson.items(f, 'network.domains.item')
        domain_count = 0
        for domain in domains:
            domain_count+=1
        row['domain_count'] = domain_count
```

**Failure Code:** (Single file open)

```
my_file_list = [f for f in glob.glob("data/jsons/*.json")]
final_result = []
for filename in my_file_list:
    row = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        info = ijson.items(f, 'info')
        for o in info:
             row['added']= float(o.get('added'))
             row['started']= float(o.get('started'))
             row['duration']= o.get('duration')
             row['ended']= float(o.get('ended'))
    
        domains = ijson.items(f, 'network.domains.item')
        domain_count = 0
        for domain in domains:
            domain_count+=1
        row['domain_count'] = domain_count
```

**Not sure this is the reason** [Using python ijson to read a large json file with multiple json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200302/using-python-ijson-to-read-a-large-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects) that ijson not able to work on multiple json element at once.

Also, let me know any other python package or any sample example that can handle large size json without memory issues.

Comment: I used https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/ for this task in my past. Worked really well. Might try it if you don't get help with ijson.

nvm. I think this is a TextIO reading issue. Details in answers section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is happening because you've finished reading your IO stream from the file, you're at the end already, and already asking for another query.

What you can do is to reset the cursor to the 0 position before the second query:

```
f.seek(0)
```

In a comment I said that you should try `json-stream` as well, but this is not an `ijson` or `json-stream` bug, it's a TextIO feature.

This is the equivalent of you opening the file a second time.

If you don't want to do this, then maybe you should look at iterating through every portion of the JSON, and then deciding for each object whether it has `info` or `network.domains.item`.

Comment: the `f.seek(0)` seems working :)

Comment: btw, I have another query, can you suggest how can I get the element counts without iterating it on ijson, e.g to get `domain_count` i,e `3`, not willing to use a for loop to get only the element counts

Comment: Well, since you still have to parse and identify those elements, it appears that iterating over them is the only way to do it. You could think about loading the data in a more structured format.

Comment: please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290769/ijson-not-working-for-multiple-object-in-large-json-file

Answer (score 1):

While the answer above is correct, you can do better: if you know the structure of your JSON file and can rely on it, you can use this to your advantage and read the file only once.

`ijson` has an even [interception mechanism](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson#intercepting-events), and the example there is very similar to what you want to achieve. In your case you want to get the `info` values, then iterate over the `network.domains.item` and count them. This should do:

```py
row = {}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    parse_events = ijson.parse(f, use_float=True)
    for prefix, event, value in parse_events:
        if prefix == 'info.added':
            row['added'] = value
        elif prefix == 'info.started':
            row['started'] = value
        elif prefix == 'info.duration':
             row['duration'] = value
        elif prefix == 'info.ended':
             row['ended'] = value
        elif prefix == 'info' and event == 'end_map':
            break
    row['domain_count'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(parse_events, 'network.domains.item'))
```

Note how:

- `ijson.items` is fed with the result of `ijson.parse`.
- `use_float=True` saves you from having to convert the values to `float` yourself.
- The counting can be done by `sum()`-ing `1` for each item coming from `ijson.items` so you don't have to loop yourself manually.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer sir. definitely try this one also.

Comment: just one query, what if I want to get the `value` and iterate it also because I have some nested array/object element that has to parse later in my json

Comment: the above solution works but multiple row sum doesn't work, only domain_count returns expected result other counts returns 0, but If I comment out domain_count then it counts perfectly

Comment: The code you shared is working fine but when I try to add another field count after `row['domain_count']` it always returns 0, e.g if I try `row['network_count']` it returns 0 but if comment out first one then it returns correct count.

Comment: please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290769/ijson-not-working-for-multiple-object-in-large-json-file