# reading large file with ijson and f.seek(0) taking too much time

Tags: python, json, seek, ijson

I have **100 thousand** of very large JSON files that I need to process on specific elements. To avoid memory overload I am using a python library called [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) which works fine when I am processing every object with preceding `f.seek(0)` to point file pointer to start but it makes my processing very very slow. Also if I remove this `f.seek(0)` the output then I am getting an error

> **premature EOF**

**Partial JSON:**

```
{
"info": {
    "added": 1638217153.782366, 
    "started": 1638261651.130148, 
    "duration": 15, 
    "ended": 1638261666.212257, 
    "owner": null, 
    "score": 0.2, 
    "id": 5062, 
    "category": "file", 
    "git": {
        "head": "13cbe0d9e457be3673304533043e992ead1ea9b2", 
        "fetch_head": "13cbe0d9e457be3673304533043e992ead1ea9b2"
    }, 
    "monitor": "2deb9ccd75d5a7a3fe05b2625b03a8639d6ee36b", 
    "package": "dll", 
    "route": "internet", 
    "custom": null, 
    "machine": {
        "status": "stopped", 
        "name": "192.168.56.1012", 
        "label": "192.168.56.1012", 
        "manager": "VirtualBox", 
        "started_on": "2021-11-30 08:40:51", 
        "shutdown_on": "2021-11-30 08:41:06"
    }, 
    "platform": "windows", 
    "version": "2.0.7", 
    "options": "procmemdump=yes,route=internet"
}, 
"network": {
    "domains": [
        {
            "ip": "87.101.200.41", 
            "domain": "www.msftncsi.com"
        }, 
        {
            "ip": "131.107.255.255", 
            "domain": "dns.msftncsi.com"
        }
    ]
}, 
"signatures": [
    {
        "families": [], 
        "description": "This executable has a PDB path", 
        "severity": 1, 
        "ttp": {}, 
        "markcount": 1, 
        "references": [], 
        "marks": [
            {
                "category": "pdb_path", 
                "ioc": "MsiHnd.pdb", 
                "type": "ioc", 
                "description": null
            }
        ], 
        "name": "has_pdb"
    }
],
"behavior": {
    "generic": [
        {
            "process_path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\lsass.exe", 
            "process_name": "lsass.exe", 
            "pid": 496, 
            "summary": {}, 
            "first_seen": 1638224353.328125, 
            "ppid": 380
        }
    ], 
    "apistats": {
        "2336": {
            "NtQueryValueKey": 2, 
            "LdrUnloadDll": 1, 
            "NtCreateSection": 1, 
            "LoadStringW": 2, 
            "CreateActCtxW": 4, 
            "NtOpenKey": 2, 
            "NtUnmapViewOfSection": 4, 
            "MessageBoxTimeoutW": 1, 
            "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter": 1, 
            "SetErrorMode": 1, 
            "NtCreateFile": 1, 
            "NtClose": 17, 
            "GetSystemTimeAsFileTime": 1, 
            "LdrLoadDll": 1, 
            "NtTerminateProcess": 3, 
            "GetFileAttributesW": 2, 
            "NtMapViewOfSection": 1
        }
    },
    "summary": {
        "file_opened": [
            "C:\\Windows\\System32\\en-US\\KERNELBASE.dll.mui"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

**Current Code:** (Multiple `f.seek(0)`) which don't want to use :)

```
my_file_list = [f for f in glob.glob("data/jsons/test.json")]
final_result = []
i = 0
for filename in my_file_list:
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
            row = {}
            parse_events = ijson.parse(f, use_float=True)
            for prefix, event, value in parse_events:
                if prefix == 'info.added':
                    row['added'] = value
                elif prefix == 'info.started':
                    row['started'] = value
                elif prefix == 'info.duration':
                     row['duration'] = value
                elif prefix == 'info.ended':
                     row['ended'] = value
                elif prefix == 'info' and event == 'end_map':
                    break
            
            f.seek(0)
            row['AF-DomainCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(f, 'network.domains.item'))
            f.seek(0)
            row['AG-SignatureCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(f, 'signatures.item'))
            f.seek(0)
            row['AH-GenericCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(f, 'behavior.generic.item'))
            f.seek(0)
            row['AI-ApistatCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(f, 'behavior.apistats'))
            f.seek(0)
            row['AJ-ProcessCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(f, 'behavior.processes.item'))
            f.seek(0)
            row['AK-SummaryCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(f, 'behavior.summary'))

            f.seek(0)
            apistats_element = ijson.items(f, 'behavior.apistats')
            for inner_apistats in apistats_element:
                for index, inner_fields in inner_apistats.items():
                    row = dict(Counter(row) + Counter(inner_fields))
            
            row['AA-Filename'] = os.path.basename(filename)
            i+=1
            print(f"processed file {i}", end='\r')
            
    except Exception as e:
        #pass
        print(f"Filename {filename} has issue with {e}")
        row = {}
    
    if row:        
        final_result.append(row)
```

**Output:** row

```
{
 'added': 1638217153.782366,
 'started': 1638261651.130148,
 'duration': 15,
 'ended': 1638261666.212257,
 'AF-DomainCount': 2,
 'AG-SignatureCount': 1,
 'AH-GenericCount': 1,
 'AI-ApistatCount': 1,
 'AK-SummaryCount': 1,
 'NtQueryValueKey': 2,
 'LdrUnloadDll': 1,
 'NtCreateSection': 1,
 'LoadStringW': 2,
 'CreateActCtxW': 4,
 'NtOpenKey': 2,
 'NtUnmapViewOfSection': 4,
 'MessageBoxTimeoutW': 1,
 'SetUnhandledExceptionFilter': 1,
 'SetErrorMode': 1,
 'NtCreateFile': 1,
 'NtClose': 17,
 'GetSystemTimeAsFileTime': 1,
 'LdrLoadDll': 1,
 'NtTerminateProcess': 3,
 'GetFileAttributesW': 2,
 'NtMapViewOfSection': 1,
 'AA-Filename': 'test.json'
}
```

**Not sure this is the reason** [Using python ijson to read a large json file with multiple json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200302/using-python-ijson-to-read-a-large-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects) that ijson not able to work on multiple json element at once.

Also, let me know any other python package or any sample example that can handle large size JSON without memory issues.

**Edit:** If I use **parse_events** without `f.seek(0)`, only `row['AF-DomainCount']` returns correct value other row counts are 0

```
row['AF-DomainCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(parse_events, 'network.domains.item'))
row['AG-SignatureCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(parse_events, 'signatures.item'))
row['AH-GenericCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(parse_events, 'behavior.generic.item'))
row['AI-ApistatCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(parse_events, 'behavior.apistats'))
row['AJ-ProcessCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(parse_events, 'behavior.processes.item'))
row['AK-SummaryCount'] = sum(1 for _ in ijson.items(parse_events, 'behavior.summary'))
```

**Note:** This is not an assignment it is a real life issue that I am facing. Basically, I need some sort of solution to avoid `f.seek(0)` multiple times and make my script faster with ijson

Comment: Perhaps using `mmap.mmap()` instead of `open()` might help?

Comment: so.. whats the goal here? tbh I dunno what's goin on in the code.

Comment: The only issue is the code is using multiple `f.seek(0)` that makes slower, not sure why ijson not working for multiple objects of JSON e.g info, network, behaviour key of the json

Answer (score 0):

I've been having my own issues with `ijson` reading large files.  I think that you are on the right track here, but if you use the `ijson.items()` method, then it is going to read the whole file just for those items and then stop, hence your need for the `f.seek(0)` calls (I think that you know this, but just for clarity).  I think that the only way around this is to use the `ijson.parse()` generator as you have, but put all of your counting/summing logic in that iterator block.

So, you might be able to do (simplified for first two counts):

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
    row = {}
    domain_count = 0
    signature_count = 0
    parse_events = ijson.parse(f, use_float=True)
    for prefix, event, value in parse_events:
        if prefix == 'info.added':
            row['added'] = value
        elif prefix == 'info.started':
            row['started'] = value
        elif prefix == 'info.duration':
             row['duration'] = value
        elif prefix == 'info.ended':
             row['ended'] = value
        elif prefix == 'network.domains.item':
            domain_count += 1
        elif prefix == 'signatures.item':
            signature_count += 1
```

This should allow you to perform those counts in a single pass of the file, instead of having to go back to the start for each one.  However, it can become challenging if your parsing logic is more complicated than just simple counts.

Also, I think that your logic for the prefixes that don't end in `.item` will all return 1; if they don't have items the generator will just return a single serialized object (and it could possibly be a very large object).