# eval vs json.loads memory consumption

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that I am writing to a file and then loading it again. The dictionary has some sets, so I have the option of either doing an `eval()` or `json.dumps()` with a custom ModelEncoder.

I tried both and `json` has a much smaller memory footprint than `eval` does. Why does `eval` take up so much more memory?

Comment: `eval` is a much more general operation. Why is it surprising that it isn't as well-optimized as a tightly-constrained one? (Also, given the extent to which those constraints rule out several classes of security bugs, why are you even *considering* `eval`?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's my data that i'm saving and reading so it's a quick way to do it.

Comment: Trusting your data is, generally speaking, an error. A well-designed deployment model will generally have code be read-only, but can't avoid having data be read-write; by evaluating data as code, you're thus defeating your ops team's efforts to prevent an attacker who can store arbitrary data from being able to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: This is **absolutely** not what eval should be used for.  Consider using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), [`msgpack`](http://msgpack.org/index.html) or similar library.

Comment: Also, `eval` is buggy when used in this context. See [Is JSON syntax a strict subset of Python syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627635/is-json-syntax-a-strict-subset-of-python-syntax)

Comment: ++[`msgpack`](http://msgpack.org/index.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether or not you should be using `eval` is really another question.

The primary reason `eval` takes more memory is the text is first compiled into a python expression (parsed, converted to byte code) and then evaluated.

Especially with large literals, python has a [memory leak in the bytecode compiler](http://bugs.python.org/issue24085).  This issue talks about pyc compilation, but you'll also hit it with code compilation in eval.

json doesn't suffer from this because it's not converting your text into executable bytecode.