# Converting a CSV file to JSON in python

Tags: python, json

So I'm trying to load in the data in csvfile, convert it to a list of dictionaries and then save the result as JSON to jsonfile. This is what I have right now. When I try to open and load the json file, I get a "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded" I'd appreciate any tips!

```
def csv_to_json(csvfile, jsonfile):
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile.splitlines(), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True,
                        fieldnames=['dept', 'code', 'section',
                                    'name', 'instructor', 'type','location])
    writer = csv.DictWriter(open(jsonfile,'wb'), fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import json
import csv


def csv_to_json(csvfile, jsonfile):
    ''''''
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
       reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['head1', 'head2']) 
       open(jsonfile, 'w').write(json.dumps(list(reader)) # if your csv file is not very large
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember JSON isn't the same that python objects/dictionaries, have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584965/2873381)
So, you must use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) to encode it, and then [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to decode it back to a valid python dict

Answer (score 0):

I wound up with this, to write arbitrary CSVs:

```
import json
import csv

def csv_to_json(csvfile, jsonfile):
    """
    Read a CSV file and output it as JSON. Assumes the csv has a header row.
    """
    with open(csvfile, 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        data_dict = []
        for row in reader:
            data_dict.append(row)
        print(len(data_dict))
        with open(jsonfile, 'w') as g:
            json.dump(data_dict, g)
```